# VBA save images as eps or other vector file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save some graphs into a folder as a vector type (e.g. eps). I am currently zooming and saving as png but this is not the optimal solution, and inserting .emf or .eps returns me an error. Below the code

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400

       ActiveChart.Export fileName:="folder\" & shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value & ".png", FilterName:="png"
```

Comment: Try exporting it as pdf. Pdf can be imported as vector after that. In CorelDRAW, for instance...

Comment: I would try Irfanview, as it supports many formats and can be automated  with command-line in vba.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testExportChartVector()
 Dim ch As Chart
   Set ch = ActiveChart
   ch.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\textChart.pdf"
End Sub
```

If you really need EPS format and you have Corel installed, it also can be manipulated from Excel VBA, through its COM VBA, like in the next code:

```
Sub testExportChartEPS()
 Dim ch As Chart, strPDF As String
   strPDF = ThisWorkbook.path & "\textChart.pdf"
   Set ch = ActiveChart
   ch.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPDF
   '____________________________________________________________________

   'Using Corel to transform pdf in eps, if strictly EPS needed:
   'Necessary a reference to "Corel - CorelDRAW xx Type Library"
   Dim cor As CorelDRAW.Application, d As CorelDRAW.Document, sh As CorelDRAW.Shape
   Dim Opt As New CorelDRAW.StructExportOptions, p As CorelDRAW.page
   Set cor = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")
     Set d = cor.createDocument
     Set p = d.Pages(1)
     p.ActiveLayer.Import strPDF
     Set sh = cor.ActiveShape
     With Opt
        .Overwrite = True
        .SizeX = sh.SizeWidth
        .SizeY = sh.SizeHeight
     End With

     d.Export left(strPDF, Len(strPDF) - 3) & ".eps", 1289, 1, Opt, Nothing
     sh.Delete

     Set cor = Nothing: Set d = Nothing: Set p = Nothing
     Set sh = Nothing: Set Opt = Nothing: Set Opt = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code has just been tested.